How to get all relations for items in database model in Django
I'm trying to make an online business canvas. In this app, we have a database containing Project, User and 9 other models. All models are connected to one specific project.
In the app, when user click on on of the items (which is stored previously in the database, I want to retrive all the related items to it. For example, when user click on a cost-structure, I have to bring everything which is related to that cost-structure or if user click on one value-proposition, I have to bring everything which is connected to that value-proposition. below is the database model:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_all_relationships(self):
        relationships = {
            'value_propositions': self.value_propositions.all(),
            'customer_segments': self.customer_segments.all(),
            'channels': self.channel.all(),
            'customer_relationships': self.customer_relationship.all(),
            'revenue_streams': self.revenue_stream.all(),
            'key_resources': self.key_resources.all(),
            'key_activities': self.key_activity.all(),
            'key_partners': self.key_partner.all(),
            'cost_structures': self.cost_structure.all(),
        }
        return relationships

class ValueProposition(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="value_propositions")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1023)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class CustomerSegment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_segments")
    value_propositions = models.ManyToManyField(ValueProposition, related_name="customer_segments")
    customer_segment = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_segment


class Channel(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="channel")
    channels = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.channels

class CustomerRelationship(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_relationship")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="customer_relationship")
    relationship=models.CharField(max_length=511)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=1023,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.relationship} , {self.description}"


class RevenueStreams(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="revenue_stream")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="revenue_stream")
    revenue = models.CharField(max_length=1023)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.revenue

class KeyResources(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="key_resources")
    value_propositions = models.ManyToManyField(ValueProposition, related_name="key_resources")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="key_resources")
    customer_relationship = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerRelationship, related_name="key_resources")
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, related_name="key_resources")
    key_resource = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1023,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.key_resource}, {self.description}"

class KeyActivities(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="key_activity")
    value_propositions = models.ManyToManyField(ValueProposition, related_name="key_activity")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="key_activity")
    customer_relationship = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerRelationship, related_name="key_activity")
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, related_name="key_activity")
    key_activity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1023,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.key_activity}, {self.description}"

class KeyPartnership(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="key_partner")
    value_propositions = models.ManyToManyField(ValueProposition, related_name="key_partner")
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="key_partner")
    customer_relationship = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerRelationship, related_name="key_partner")
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, related_name="key_partner")
    key_partner = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1023,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.key_partner} ,{self.description}"

class CostStructure(models.Model):
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cost_structure")
    value_propositions = models.ManyToManyField(ValueProposition, related_name="cost_structure",blank=True)
    customer_segment = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerSegment, related_name="cost_structure",blank=True )
    customer_relationship = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerRelationship, related_name="cost_structure",blank=True)
    channel = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, related_name="cost_structure",blank=True)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1023,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.cost},{self.description}"



I send request with AJAX to my REST api and this is what I've done yet:
in the AJAX, section is the part that request comes from for example if user clicked on a value-proposition, its value-proposition. itemID is the ID of the item which user clicked on it. projectname uses to retrive the Project from DB. I have to handle this part in the matter which it doesnt care what user clicked, I can get all relation of that item.
def ViewInCanvas(request):
    user = request.user
    webdata = json.loads(request.body)
    projectname = webdata['projectname']
    section = webdata['section']
    itemID = webdata['itemID']

    try:
        project = Project.objects.get(name=projectname, user=user)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Project Doesn't Exist"}, status=500)

    try:
        item= handler_functions[section](project=project,pk=itemID)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Project Doesn't Exist"}, status=500)

handler_functions = {
    "value-proposition": ValueProposition.objects.get,
    "customer-segment": CustomerSegment.objects.get,
    "channel": Channel.objects.get,
    "customer-relationship": CustomerRelationship.objects.get,
    "revenue-stream": RevenueStreams.objects.get,
    "key-resources": KeyResources.objects.get,
    "key-activities": KeyActivities.objects.get,
    "key-partnership": KeyPartnership.objects.get,
    "cost-structure": CostStructure.objects.get,
}

